# How to stick to bottom certain Item of FlatList?

Tags: react-native

There is such prop of `FlatList` for the stick it to top - `stickyHeaderIndices`, but not to bottom. 
Is there a way to do it with some built-in `React Native` staff?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the docs on FlatList there is this property: ListFooterComponent where a Item of your list can be rendered.

Quote: "Rendered at the bottom of all the items. Can be a React Component Class, a render function, or a **rendered element**."

Maybe try to play around with this.